# Adding a text file to the start of my code causes a parsing error

Tags: c#, python, eof

I'm using this python script to add a copyright spiel to the start of all my C# scripts

```
import re
import shutil
import os

copyrightloc =  'C:/DATA/pyscripts/copyright.txt'
rootdir = 'C:/DATA/pyscripts/02_CODE'
dstdir = 'C:/DATA/pyscripts/codecopy'

spielfile =  open(copyrightloc, "r") 
spiel = spielfile.read() 

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".cs"):
            with open(subdir+'/'+file, "r+") as codefile ,  open(dstdir+'/'+file, 'w') as destfile:
                destfile.write(spiel+'\n' + codefile.read())
```

As you can see I am adding the original string to the copyright string and writing it to a new file.

The files look fine when theyre finished but in every file, at the first line of the original file, I get a parsing error. For example, below shows an exerpt from the new file at the end of the copyright speil and the beginning of the original file...

```
          BLAH BLAH BLAH COPYRIGHT
  * OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING
  * FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
  * CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING OUT OF OR IN
  * CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES.
  */


using UnityEngine;   [!!!ERROR IS SHOWN ON THIS LINE!!!]
using System.Collections;

public class Floop : MonoBehaviour {

    public rot glorb;
    public GameObject foo;

              BLAH BLAH BLAH MY CODE
```

I'm guessing there is some invisible character there like "end of file" or something but I cannot see anything in notepad++ when I select "show all characters" ... If I go to the start of the line in question and hit delete the error goes away..
How can I make my python script avoid this problem?

Comment: "BLAH BLAH BLAH COPYRIGHT" is not commented out

Comment: You are using C-style comments in C#

Comment: what is precisely your parse error ?

Comment: @ Xavier. monodevelop/unity is just telling me "parsing error" Though i noticed even notepad++ is picking up on something as the text highlighting goes off for thst "using UnityEngine" bit and it returns if I delete that non-existant character

Comment: And what does `print repr(spiel.splitlines()[0])` show is in that text? Anything suspicious? Do you perhaps have a UTF-8 BOM or similar there? (`'\xef\xbb\xbf'` at the start).

Comment: Try changing it to `destfile.write(spiel+'\r\n' + codefile.read())`. This might be necessary since you haven't opened the files in text mode (`"rt+"` and `"wt"`) which would handle end-of-line character translations automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is chance that in your copyright text there is unicode characters not properly encoded try use the codecs module

```
import re
import shutil
import os
import codecs

copyrightloc =  'C:/DATA/pyscripts/copyright.txt'
rootdir = 'C:/DATA/pyscripts/02_CODE'
dstdir = 'C:/DATA/pyscripts/codecopy'

spielfile =  codecs.open(copyrightloc, "r", encoding="utf8") 
spiel = spielfile.read() 

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".cs"):
            with codecs.open(subdir+'/'+file, "r+",encoding="utf8") as codefile ,  open(dstdir+'/'+file, 'w') as destfile:
                destfile.write(spiel+'\n' + codefile.read())
```

Comment: cheers. I will try this soon (like next few daysish) and give you bounty if it works

Comment: I'd use `io.open()` instead; the `codecs` module file objects have several bugs that the (much better architected) `io` module doesn't suffer from.

Comment: This code **will not work** unless you also *encode* again when writing out!

Answer (score 5):

The [MSDN C# style guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) says you should not use blocks of asterisks around comments. Can you try prefixing each line of the copyright with `//`?

[Alternatively](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Syntax), you may be able to use this format (note lack of asterisk at the beginning of each line):

```
/*
copyright here
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your files contains a 'Byte order mark', which are some special characters at the beginning of the file to indicate the encoding.

Check this with a HEX editor if you see some extra characters before the ones that you expect.

If this is the case, then you should use the 'utf-8-sig' encoding. I'm not a python export, but your code could then look like this

```
...
spielfile =  codecs.open(copyrightloc, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
...
with codecs.open(subdir+'/'+file, "r+", encoding="utf-8-sig") as codefile ,  open(dstdir+'/'+file, 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as destfile:
```